# Rendering in openGL only after turning my screen off and then on

Tags: android, textures, opengl-es-2.0, onpause

The following problem is reported on only with devices having Ardeno GPU. With devices having Mali GPU, the problem doesn't exist.

The problem:
I'm rendering textures and using render when dirty.The rendering of the textures does not happen and I only see a black screen. However, if I turn off screen, and turn it on again, AND THEN request render (by say glSurfaceView.requestRender();), it renders the textures properly.

Any ideas why this behavior is happening?

Comment: Hi @Aditya, I was wondering if you found a solution for this issue?

Comment: No, not yet... I somehow feel it's something to do with onCreate().